# How to clear settings using azure cli and rest command?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli

I want to remove settings from `keyVaultReferenceIdentity`

```
az rest --method PATCH --uri "${resourceId}?api-version=2021-01-01" --body "{""properties"":{""keyVaultReferenceIdentity"":null}}" --query properties.keyVaultReferenceIdentity -o json
```

But for this I have

> Unsupported Media Type({"error":{"code":"UnsupportedMediaType","message":"The content media type '' is not supported. Only 'application/json' is supported."}})

If I add headers:

```
$headers = @{"Content-Type" = "application/json" }


az rest --method PATCH --Headers $headers --uri "${resourceId}?api-version=2021-01-01" --body "{""properties"":{""keyVaultReferenceIdentity"":null}}" --query properties.keyVaultReferenceIdentity -o json
```

then:

> The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
> not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/util.py", line 506, in shell_safe_json_parse
> File "json_*init*_.py", line 370, in loads
> File "json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
> File "json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/util.py", line 815, in send_raw_request
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/util.py", line 531, in shell_safe_json_parse
> azure.cli.core.azclierror.InvalidArgumentValueError: Failed to parse JSON: System.Collections.Hashtable
> Error detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 657, in execute
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 691, in _run_job
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 328, in **call**
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/util/custom.py", line 16, in rest_call
> File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/util.py", line 818, in send_raw_request
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Idea is to clear `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` however I can find valid syntax and parameters combination.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13056) on GH but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I did a repro with your CLI command and modified according to correct format and fixed, below is the CLI command where we can execute it without getting any errors.

> az rest --method patch --headers "{'Content-Type':
> 'application/json'}" --uri
> /subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/CheckingLogs0805?api-version=2015-08-01
> --body "{'properties': {'siteConfig': {'keyVaultReferenceIdentity':null}}}" --query
> properties.keyVaultReferenceIdentity -o json

So, above command will fix the error messages which you have shown (i.e., UnsupportedMediaType and JSONDecodeError

Now coming to the question to clear the value of 'keyVaultReferenceIdentity'. This usually sets by default while creation as SystemAssigned. These values are taken from Managed Identities.

Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types) for the values System Identity and Managed Identity.

From the command which I have fixed, we can change the value of any other parameter.

Refer to screenshot as I have changed value of 'properties': {"enabled": true}

[image: LocalScreenshot]

Comment: You set `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` on siteCofnig. But there are two settings with this name. One is directly on `properties` and one is on `protperties.siteConfig`. Do you know why there are two? And why the first one is used [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references.md)